# tweepy (python): rate limit exceeded code 88

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm writing a Twitter application with tweepy that crawls up the tweets by looking at in_reply_to_status_ID. 
Everything works fine up to the rate limit, after a few minutes, I have to wait another 15 minutes or so.

This is strange because I used nearly identical code until a few months ago before API 1.0 got deprecated, and it didn't have the rate limit problem.

Is there a known way I can get rid of, or at least increase the rate limit?
Or is there a workaround?

Seems like a lot of people are having trouble with this, but can't find a definite solution..

i will greatly appreciate it if you could help.

```
auth1 = tweepy.auth.OAuthHandler('consumer_token','consumer_secret')
auth1.set_access_token('access_token','access_secret')
api=tweepy.API(auth1)

def hasParent(s):
    #return true if s is not None, i.e., s is an in_reply_to_status_id numbe 
....

while hasParent(ps):
    try:
        parent=api.get_status(ps)
    except tweepy.error.TweepError:
        print 'tweeperror'
        break
    newparent = parent.in_reply_to_status_id
        ......
    ps=newparent
```

Comment: exactly same issue ...did u solve it out?

Comment: [Rate Limitation on Twitter API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/rate-limiting)

Answer (score 2):

I put a limit and worked:

```js
def index(request):
    statuses = tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline).items(10)
    return TemplateResponse(request, 'index.html', {'statuses': statuses})
```

Comment: thank you for posting! Could you please explain the logic behind your answer, and how it could apply to my case?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to you reached max limit. Just disconnect your internet connection and reconnect again, no need to wait. 
Use cursor:

`statuses = tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline).items(2)`

If you get the error again, just reduce items.