# Sleep when requesting profile pictures from Twitter?

Tags: python-3.x, twitter

quite a noob in Python here. For a project, I need to download profile pictures of a list of twitter accounts. I already requested from the API the URLs of the pictures and now I should download them. I was just wondering whether I should make my script sleep and if so how much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Avoid Twitter API limitation with Tweepy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21308762/avoid-twitter-api-limitation-with-tweepy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be faster to use threads. Then, pictures will download concurrently. If you have all the urls in an array you could use a `ThreadPool`, as in this example

https://markhneedham.com/blog/2018/07/15/python-parallel-download-files-requests/