# Tweepy rate limit / pagination issue.

Tags: django, python-2.7, twitter, tweepy, django-1.6

I've put together a small twitter tool to pull relevant tweets, for later analysis in a latent semantic analysis.  Ironically, that bit (the more complicated bit) works fine - it's pulling the tweets that's the problem.  I'm using the code below to set it up.

This technically works, but no as expected - the .items(200) parameter I thought would pull 200 tweets per request, but it's being blocked into 15 tweet chunks (so the 200 items 'costs' me 13 requests) - I understand that this is the original/default RPP variable (now 'count' in the Twitter docs), but I've tried that in the Cursor setting (rpp=100, which is the maximum from the twitter documentation), and it makes no difference.

[Tweepy/Cursor docs](http://tweepy.readthedocs.org/en/v2.3.0/api.html?highlight=cursor)
[The other nearest similar question isn't quite the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20559425/tweepy-python-rate-limit-exceeded-code-88)

Grateful for any thoughts!  I'm sure it's a minor tweak to the settings, but I've tried various settings on page and rpp, to no avail.

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(apikey, apisecret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret_var)
from tools import read_user, read_tweet
from auth import basic
api = tweepy.API(auth)
current_results = []
from tweepy import Cursor
for tweet in Cursor(api.search,
                       q=search_string,
                       result_type="recent",
                       include_entities=True,
                       lang="en").items(200):
    current_user, created = read_user(tweet.author)
    current_tweet, created = read_tweet(tweet, current_user)
    current_results.append(tweet)
print current_results
```

Comment: Any idea on how to get the count of the tweets for a particular hashtag at an instant? I am using `trends_place` to get the trends specific to a country. I want more information which includes the number of tweets for a particular hashtag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I worked it out in the end, with a little assistance from colleagues.  Afaict, the rpp and items() calls are coming after the actual API call.  The 'count' option from the [Twitter documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets) which was formerly RPP as mentioned above, and is still noted as rpp in Tweepy 2.3.0, seems to be at issue here.

What I ended up doing was modifying the Tweepy Code - in api.py, I added 'count' in to the search bind section (around L643 in my install, ymmv).

```
""" search """
search = bind_api(
    path = '/search/tweets.json',
    payload_type = 'search_results',
    allowed_param = ['q', 'count', 'lang', 'locale', 'since_id', 'geocode', 'max_id', 'since', 'until', 'result_type', **'count**', 'include_entities', 'from', 'to', 'source']
)
```

This allowed me to tweak the code above to:

```
for tweet in Cursor(api.search,
                       q=search_string,
                       count=100,
                       result_type="recent",
                       include_entities=True,
                       lang="en").items(200):
```

Which results in two calls, not fifteen; I've double checked this with

```
print api.rate_limit_status()["resources"]
```

after each call, and it's only deprecating my remaining searches by 2 each time.

Comment: Yeah, I have to wait another 12 hours to do it. :)