# Accessing users who are using an specific Twitter hashtag in python

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to access a representative data about one hashtag using Twitter search API. I am using python and tweepy. However, it returns a limited number of tweets? could you give me a hint why it happens?

The code which I am using is as follows:

```
import tweepy
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener

ckey = 'ckey'
csecret = 'csecret'
atoken = 'tok'
asecret = 'atok'

class Listener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        print data
        return True

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        print status_code

auth = OAuthHandler('key1',      'key2')
api = tweepy.API(auth)
 #auth.set_access_token('key3', 'key4')

#twitterStream = Stream(auth, Listener())
#twitterStream.filter(track=["car"])
#twitterStream.sample()

users = []

count = 1
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=('"#bgnow"')).items(500):
#ding thru all tweets and extract the name of non-duplicate

    print "Name:", tweet.author.name.encode('utf8')
    print "Tweet created:", tweet.created_at
    user = tweet.author.screen_name.encode('utf8')
    print user
    print "//////////////////"
    if not users.__contains__(user):
        users.append(user)
    count += 1
    print count


print '====================List of unique users in total' + str(len(users))
for u in users:
    print u
```

This code only returns a list 135 tweets in which there is only 70 distinct users. Why does it return this limited number of tweets?
How can I get more users?

Comment: I hope theses are not your actual auth credentials.

Comment: Maybe it's the default pagination limit.

Comment: Also, check the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26473393/tweepy-rate-limit-pagination-issue

Comment: Thanks @bad_keypoints. This post indeed was useful.